# Некорректное чтение с файла

Tags: c, файлы, вывод, файловый-ввод-вывод

Помогите исправить проблему или посоветуйте как лучше сделать.
В файле записано вот это:

Test marka 1  Ukraine  2014  23  color cool

Test marka 2  Russia  1986  43  rare

Вот чтение с файла и вывод на экран
[image: А вот что выдает в консоли]

```
fscanf(read,"%s  %s  %d  %d  %s\n",&info[i].name,&info[i].country,&info[i].year,&info[i].cost,&info[i].feat);
            printf("Info of mark num %d\n",i+1);
            printf("Name: %s\n",info[i].name);
            printf("Country: %s\n",info[i].country);
            printf("Year: %d\n",info[i].year);
            printf("Cost: %d\n",info[i].cost);
            printf("Features: %s\n",info[i].feat);`
```

Comment: Чтения здесь не видно...

Comment: @Harry `fscanf(read,"%s  %s  %d  %d  %s\n",&info[i].name,&info[i].country,&info[i].year,&info[i].cost,&info[i].feat);` вот, не знаю почему его там не отображает

Comment: @Harry Name типа char: (Test marka 1); Country char: (Ukraine); Year char: (2014); Cost char : (23); Features char: (color cool)

Comment: Для начала - `char` или `char[]`? Ну, а потом - все равно надо менять чтение.

Comment: @Harry Можете помочь, как его изменить? Я не могу больше ничего придумать

Answer (score 1):

Итак,

```
fscanf(read,"%s  %s  %d  %d  %s\n",&info[i].name,&info[i].country,&info[i].year,
       &info[i].cost,&info[i].feat);
```

Строка `Test marka 1 Ukraine 2014 23 color cool`. Не знаю, какого типа у вас поля структуры, но даже если все верно (во что я не верю по вашей записи...), то считывается так

```
name       Test
country    marka
year       1
cost       Ukraine  (должно считываться число! Но это не число. Чтение завершено)
feat       2014     (уже не читается - из-за неверного чтения предыдущего поля)
```

Следующее чтение начинается с того места, где остановилось предыдущее -

```
name       Ukraine
country    2014
year       23
cost       color  (опять не считывается - это не число!)
```

ну, и так далее...

Так что начинайте с написания правильного вызова [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)...